# Unable to click on items in a css hamburger menu

Tags: css, responsive-design

I'm building a hamburger menu for a mobile website using only html and css. You can view the code [here on codepen.io](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XKgbza).

```
<html>
 <body>
  <nav>

  <button class="hamburger"><span></span></button>

  <div class="close"></div>

  <ul class="menu">
   <li><a href="Page1">Page1</a></li>

   <li><a href="Page2">Page2</a></li>

   <li><a href="Page3">Page3</a></li>

   <li><a href="Page4">Page4</a></li>

   <li><a href="http://google.com">Google</a></li>
  </ul>

  </nav>
 </body>
</html>
```

As you can see from line 106 in the css part

```
.hamburger:focus ~ .menu {
visibility: visible;
}
```

the menu is visible when the button is in focus. The Problem is that as soon as you click on a menu item, the button gets out of focus and the menu disappears before the click can be processed.
I already tried to write rules for the focussed menu, but it did not help.

Please let me know if you need any additional information.
Thank you in advance for your effort.

Comment: add transition: visibility 0.5s; on your menu class, I've posted an answer check it out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add transition visibility on your menu class. see the updated class below.

```css
.menu {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  visibility: hidden;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #333;
  transition: visibility 0.5s;
}

.menu a {
  color: #87BF58;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.hamburger {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 3rem;
  width: 3rem;
  z-index: 500;
  text-indent: 0;
  appearance: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background 0.3s;
  background-color: yellowgreen;
}

.hamburger:focus {
  outline: none;
  background-color: green;
}

.hamburger span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
  left: 25%;
  right: 25%;
  height: 10%;
  background: white;
  transition: background 0s 0.3s;
}

.hamburger span::before,
.hamburger span::after {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  content: "";
  transition-duration: 0.3s, 0.3s;
  transition-delay: 0.3s, 0s;
}

.hamburger span::before {
  top: -210%;
  transition-property: top, transform;
}

.hamburger span::after {
  bottom: -210%;
  transition-property: bottom, transform;
}

.hamburger:focus span {
  background: none;
}

.hamburger:focus span::before {
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.hamburger:focus span::after {
  bottom: 0;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);

}

.hamburger:focus span::before,
.hamburger:focus span::after {
  transition-delay: 0s, 0.3s;

}

.close {
  position: absolute;
  height: 3rem;
  width: 3rem;
  margin-top: -3rem;
  z-index: 501;
  background-color: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.hamburger:focus ~ .menu {
  visibility: visible;
}

.hamburger:focus ~ .close {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
 <nav>


    <button class="hamburger"><span></span></button>

    <div class="close"></div>

    <ul class="menu">
      <li><a href="Page1">Page1</a></li>

      <li><a href="Page2">Page2</a></li>

      <li><a href="Page3">Page3</a></li>

      <li><a href="Page4">Page4</a></li>

      <li><a href="google.com">Google</a></li>
    </ul>

  </nav>
```

Comment: Thank you @Allan . I'm currently checking if your suggestion works for my usecase. As soon as I'm done testing, I will mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: No problem pal :) hope it works on your use case too. although I'm positive about it  :P